# How to remove text ellipsis in Bot messages format (Google Chat API)

Tags: google-hangouts

I am using webhook integration for contact form with the help of google chat API.
I am done with the implementation. I am facing an issue with text formatting. The text is coming only in a single line and the rest of the text is getting trimmed (see the attached screenshot).

Is there an option that will allow the text to come in the next line if the width of text exceeds the width of bot-message instead of text-ellipsis?

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming you are using text paragraph in your card message. Do you really expect a continuous message without spaces? I also encountered similar behavior using my test bot. But when I include spaces between them, it was expanded correctly without ellipsis.

Comment: I'm using the syntax like this:  {\"keyValue\":{\"topLabel\":\"Comments\", \"content\":\"$comments\"}}.
Can you please give me an example of how should I use text paragraph? In my current implementation, I'm using content.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Suraj, I tried it both with text paragraph and with key value. In key value, even though I set contentMultiline to true , but if your comments contains a single long word, it will still appear in ellipsis form. You can try providing a valid comment (not single long word) as your sample message

Comment: Hi @RonM, I have tried setting contentMultiline to true but can't fix the issue. Is it the issue with assigning a variable with a dynamic value?
In your first reply, you had mentioned about to include the spaces. Can you please help me with a syntax of how and where should I add spaces.
Thanks!

Comment: I just put spaces in my sample message example: comments = "sdfghasss ssssss sssss ssss ... so on"